# In R, how can one make a method of an S4 object that directly adjusts the values inside the slots of that object?

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

Is there a way to allow a method of an S4 object to directly adjust the values inside the slots of that object without copying the entire object into memory and having to re-write it to the parent environment at the end of the method?  Right now I have an object that has slots where it keeps track of its own state.  I call a method that advances it to the next state, but right now it seems like I have to assign() each value (or a copy of the object invoking the method) back to the parent environment.  As a result, the object oriented code seems to be running *a lot* slower than code that simply adjusts the various state variables in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question on the R-list myself, and found a work-around to simulate a pass by reference, something in the style of :

```
eval(
  eval(
     substitute(
        expression(object@slot <<- value)
     ,env=parent.frame(1) )
  )
)
```

Far from the cleanest code around I'd say...

A suggestion coming from the R-help list, uses an environment to deal with these cases.
EDIT : tweaked code inserted.

```
setClass("MyClass", representation(.cache='environment',masterlist="list"))

setMethod("initialize", "MyClass",
  function(.Object, .cache=new.env()) {
    .Object@masterlist <- list()
    callNextMethod(.Object, .cache=.cache)
  })

sv <- function(object,name,value) {} #store value

setMethod("sv",signature=c("MyClass","character","vector"),
  function(object, name, value) {
    object@.cache$masterlist[[name]] <- value
  })

rv <- function(object,name) {} #retrieve value

setMethod("rv",signature=c("MyClass","character"),
  function(object, name) {
    return(object@.cache$masterlist[[name]])
  })
```

Comment: Tweaked so it works.
setClass("MyClass", representation(.cache='environment',masterlist="list"))
setMethod("initialize", "MyClass",
function(.Object, .cache=new.env()) {
 .Object@masterlist <- list()
 callNextMethod(.Object, .cache=.cache)
})

sv <- function(object,name,value) {} #store value
setMethod("sv",signature=c("MyClass","character","vector"),
function(object, name, value) {
 object@.cache$masterlist[[name]] <- value
})

rv <- function(object,name) {} #retrieve value
setMethod("rv",signature=c("MyClass","character"),
function(object, name) {
 return(object@.cache$masterlist[[name]])
})

Comment: The code as written doesn't actually store a value to a variable defined by "name" in the call, it just stores it blindly in a variable called name.  By putting a list in the environment we can then restore values by name, although stored data structures may be mangled and need to be recast when returning to regular use.

Comment: I'm not completely following your code. You make a masterlist as a slot in the object, and then again in the .cache environment. Isn't that a bit overshoot? The one as a slot in the object doesn't serve a purpose. You can change vars there using the eval-construct I mentioned, but that's hardly to be called good programming.

Comment: It has been quite a while since I looked at this, and I'm not following my code either.  The lack of line breaks certainly doesn't help. What I'm trying to see if where my code differs from what you have above.  I never dove into S4 classes much, so I had to relearn how to even test the basic version.  At any rate, the new answer involving Reference Classes is probably a good place for people to look who have the sort of question I had back then.

Answer (score 4):

R has three object oriented (OO) systems: **S3**, **S4** and **Reference Classes** (where the latter were for a while referred to as [[R5]], yet their official name is Reference Classes).

Reference Classes (or refclasses) are new in R 2.12. They fill a long standing need for mutable objects that had previously been filled by non-core packages like R.oo, proto and mutatr. While the core functionality is solid, reference classes are still under active development and some details will change. The most up-to-date documentation for Reference Classes can always be found in ?ReferenceClasses.

There are two main differences between reference classes and S3 and S4:

- Refclass objects use message-passing OO
- Refclass objects are mutable: the usual R copy on modify semantics do
  not apply.

These properties makes this object system behave much more like Java and C#. 
read more here:

1. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/R5.html
2. http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/methods/ReferenceClasses

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (and if I get you correctly), you have to recopy the whole object. You can't easily pass values by reference, it is always passed "by value". So once you have modified (a copy of) your object, you need to recopy it back to your object.

John Chamber is pretty explicit about it in his book [Software for Data Analysis](http://www.springer.com/statistics/computanional+statistics/book/978-0-387-75935-7). It's a way to avoid surprises or side effects.

I think there are some workaround using environments, but I can't help with this.

Comment: It sounds like you understand my question correctly.  I understand the motive and in many contexts it makes sense, but being safe here (the application: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1286/how-can-i-obtain-some-of-all-possible-combinations-in-r) is costing me a lot in terms of speed, which is why I was looking for another approach.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Rprof() to make sure the critical point is really where you think ? Or maybe you could try to use ff() to allow bigger matrices (reusing combn() code)

Comment: I'm not sure how to use Rprof() effectively is there a guide somewhere?

Comment: Right now when I try to use Rprof my code dies with the error message "Error in .getClassFromCache(Class, where) : caught access violation - continue with care".